# React Recharts, difference between chromium and firefox

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, firefox, chromium, recharts

I have a stacked area chart with a time series. I'm normalizing the data to always add up to 100%.
With some specific data, the chart breaks, and used to break in the same way in firefox until I added `scale="time"` to `XAxis`.
Right now this is what I have:

```
<AreaChart data={percentData.sort((a, b) => a.name >= b.name)}>
    <defs>
        {colors.map((c, i) => (
            <linearGradient id={`graphColor${i}`} x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="1" key={c}>
                <stop offset="5%" stopColor={c} stopOpacity={1} />
                <stop offset="95%" stopColor={c} stopOpacity={0.5} />
            </linearGradient>
        ))}
        {customGradients()}
    </defs>
    <XAxis
        dataKey="name"
        type="number"
        domain={[MIN, MAX]}
        scale="time"
        tickFormatter={dateFormatter}
        ticks={tickArray}
        tickCount={5}
    >
        <Label value="Date" position="bottom" style={{ textAnchor: 'middle' }} />
    </XAxis>
    <YAxis ticks={[0, 25, 50, 75, 100]} domain={[0, 100]} unit="%" type="number">
        <Label angle={-90} value="Percentage" position="insideLeft" style={{ textAnchor: 'middle' }} />
    </YAxis>
    <Tooltip content={<CustomTooltip tickFormatter={dateFormatter} />} />
    <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3" />
    {tab
        && tab.keys
            .sort()
            .map((k, i) => (
                <Area
                    type="monotone"
                    dataKey={k}
                    stroke={tab.data[`${k}color`] || getColorForCurrentIndex(i)}
                    fillOpacity={1}
                    fill={
                        tab.data[`${k}color`]
                            ? `url(#graphColor${k}color)`
                            : `url(#graphColor${getColorIndex(i)})`
                    }
                    key={k}
                    stackId="1"
                />
            ))}
</AreaChart>
```

The console in chromium outputs the following:

```
Error: <rect> attribute x: Expected length, "NaN".
Error: <rect> attribute width: Expected length, "NaN".
```

I'm using unix timestamps for the x coordinates, they are proper number instances.

And this is the result in firefox:
[Firefox stacked time series area chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wrj7C.png)

The first render on chromium:
[Chromium stacked time series area chart first render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WiHT7.png)

After re-render on chromium:
[Chromium stacked time series area chart second render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7qkI.png)

Any help is appreciated, struggling with figuring this out. Thanks!

I've tried the example for [Percent area chart](https://recharts.org/en-US/examples/PercentAreaChart) provided in recharts docs, same result.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I wasn't sorting my data properly, even though they were numbers passed to a numeric axis, sorting the data array fixed this issue:

`sort((a, b) => a.name >= b.name)` => `sort((a, b) => a.name - b.name)`